# Using typeof in ternary

Tags: javascript, ternary

Im looping(hence the i) through a `json object(jobj)` and checking values, changing them if necessary.

```js
(jobj["Level_Objects"][i]["x"] <0 || jobj["Level_Objects"][i]["x"]>0) ? true : jobj["Level_Objects"][i]["x"]=0;
```

That works as expected, allowing for neg and pos numbers and setting it to 0 if neither.

My problem is that I want to check using `typeof` as well, none of the syntax iv tried works.

```js
(typeof jobj["Level_Objects"][i]["x"]==="number" || jobj["Level_Objects"][i]["x"] <0 || jobj["Level_Objects"][i]["x"]>0) ? true : jobj["Level_Objects"][i]["x"]=0;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following, it will will assign zero if the value is not a number.

```js
const value = jobj['Level_Objects'][i]['x']

if (typeof value !== 'number') {
  jobj['Level_Objects'][i]['x'] = 0
}
// or without the if
jobj['Level_Objects'][i]['x'] = typeof value === 'number' ? value : 0
```

Comment: This works, and I think I can work with it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Great, don't forget to accept the answer.